# How to handle multiple Akka Actors?

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor

My actual use case is that MyActor receives a message to begin it's job. The job needs to download several webpages, so it asks MyActor to download. MyActor responds each time an article finishes downloading.

Is there a better design pattern for my code? It seems like allowing multiple actors to update the count variable is bad, since I only care about the count specific to each actor.

Main Actor:

```
val count = 0

def receive = {
    case CountUpdate => count += 1
    case Job => {   

        List(1, 2, 3).map{case num => 
            (new myActor ? ToDownload)

            val tries = 0
            while (tries < 10){
               print("Count is: " + count)
               tries += 1
               // sleep 10 seconds
            }

            count = 0
        }           
    }
}
```

MyActor:

```
def receive = {
    case ToDownload => sender ! CountUpdate
}
```

Edit:

If I follow the suggestion to use futures, couldn't this could cause a race condition?

```
 var downloads: List[Int] = List()

 urls.map{ case url => Future{ download(url) }.onComplete{
    case Success(value) => downloads = downloads :+ value
    case Failure(value) => println("Failure")
    }
 }
```

Comment: I don't believe that CountUpdate handler will run while the Job handler is running -- the Actor handles messages one at a time from the mailbox. So MyActor will push CountUpdates into the mailbox, but these wont be reflected in the count variable, as you will still be processing Job.

Comment: Thank you @RichHenry , this is true and I did not think about that!

Comment: Np, i made the same mistake and i solved it with a Promise as I answered below. Though keep in mind I dont think that Promise can be sent to a remote actor -- tho i dont know for sure.

Comment: @RichHenry , what do you think of using futures, as I described in my edit?

Comment: Yes that is a race condition as you don't control when the future callback gets executed, so you will need to synchronize that code somehow (or use a thread-safe list implementation from Java). The danger is that you will lose updates as one Future can overwrite another before it does the assignment.

Comment: You're getting closer though, as you can combine multiple futures together into a composite future and then act when all the resources are loaded -- you dont have to keep track of them in a list like that.

Comment: The behavior that follows is based upon downloads.size at certain time intervals

Comment: You may want to browse the Akka Streams stuff. It makes this kind of work much easier. It has a functional interface and makes the actors for you, and it has backpressure to control WIP.

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a `Future` to download the resources. Once the future has completed you can send an update message to the main actor which can react to it. The `Future` is executed by the `executionContext`.

```scala
class MainActor extends Actor {
  var count = 0

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case CountUpdate =>
      count += 1
      println("New count " + count)
    case Job =>
      val batchIDs = List(1, 2, 3)

      implicit val executionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(new ForkJoinPool())

      batchIDs.map {
        batchID =>
          Future {
            // do some work
          }.onSuccess{
            case _ => self ! CountUpdate
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think my explanation might not be clear enough. Each item in List(1, 2, 3) represents batches of things to download that need to remain separate, instead of single files. I guess if it responded with a "batch_id" field, the MainActor could sort by batch_id. Thank you!

Comment: That is not a problem. You can also create a list which contains the batches. Then, each element of the `map` operation defines what resources shall be downloaded. Here I only implemented it with single files as an example.

Comment: @user2827214 I updated the code. Do you meant something like that?

Comment: If you make the "var count" into a hashmap that maps the batch_id to the count for that specific batch_id

Answer (score 1):

I would send a `scala.concurrent.Promise` to the resource loading actor, and then you can get call `.future` on it to get a `scala.concurrent.Future`.

The resource loader calls `.complete()` on the `Promise`, and this in turn will cause the complete handler on the `Future` to be called.